# Django Returning Items outside filter when filtering by time

Tags: python, django

I have a snippet of code designed to grab the entries that are <24 hours old

```py
            yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)

            items = get_model(name=p).objects.filter(tagid=tag.id, t_stamp__gt=yesterday).order_by('t_stamp')
            for i in items:
                print(f'{i.t_stamp}  - {i.t_stamp > yesterday}')
            print(yesterday)
```

Yet for some reason, it returns 2 items, when it should return 0.

Results of the print statement above:

```
2023-04-06 13:12:54.540000  - False
2023-04-06 14:12:46.976000  - False
2023-04-10 10:06:27.526066
```

As you can see, the timestamp is NOT greater than `yesterday`, so why is it being returned?

---

## Edit

After further troubleshooting, the issue was since `t_stamp` was a custom field that converted a timestamp to a `datetime` object, I needed to override `get_prep_value()` to convert it back into an int properly.

Comment: How do you initialize `yesterday`?

Comment: @lucutzu33 added to my post.  I used `yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)`

Comment: I guess `.filter()` uses or-combination for its individual arguments. Chain your filters: `...objects.filter(tagid=tag.id).filter(t_stamp__gt=yesterday).order_by(...`.

Comment: To refute my guess: the [documentation for filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#filter) states the arguments are and-ed. But you can still try to see if chaining the filters makes a difference. Or just removing the tagid filter completely.

Comment: Do print i.tagid as well for each object. And at the top or bottom of the output, please print `tag.id` next to `yesterday`.

Comment: How is `t_stamp` stored in the database? Can you share the model definition?

Comment: "that converted a timestamp to a datetime object": how is a timestamp different than a datetime object?

Comment: NB: your "edit" shouldn't be an edit, but an answer, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

After further troubleshooting, the issue was since t_stamp was a custom field that converted a timestamp to a datetime object, I needed to override get_prep_value() to convert it back into an int properly.

```py
class TimestampField(models.Field):
    """
    Casts BigIntField to a python datetime object
    """
    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(value / 1000)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, datetime):
            return value
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(value / 1000)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, datetime):
            return int(value.timestamp() * 1000)
        return value
```